# Conditional error in Terraform: Error: Incorrect attribute value type

Tags: if-statement, terraform, conditional-statements, terraform-provider-aws

I am calling a module (Terraform v0.13.7) and have this statement to determine an AWS SNS Alarm action (if environment is production, use this, otherwise use this):

```
alarm_sns_topic_arn = var.environment == "production" ? data.terraform_remote_state.outputs.alarm_sns_topic_arn["foo1"] : data.terraform_remote_state.outputs.alarm_sns_topic_arn["foo2"]
```

When run, I get an error `Error: Incorrect attribute value type`. The variable `alarm_sns_topic_arn` is a string type. foo1 and foo2 should resolve to the correct ARN values, and I confirmed that when hardcoding the values it fails as well.

The full error reads:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../../modules/aws/elasticache_cluster/cloudwatch.tf line 70, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "elasticache_alarm":
  70:   alarm_actions       = var.alarm_sns_topic_arn                                                                                                # This variable is currently a null default

Inappropriate value for attribute "alarm_actions": set of string required.
```

Banging my head against the wall — what am I missing?

Comment: Please provide data source  terraform_remote_state defination and "alarm_sns_topic_arn" variable type mentioned in ../../../modules/aws/elasticache_cluster/variables.tf

Comment: I figured out my issue, was not specifying a list when the attribute required it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is embarrassing, and of course makes sense in light of the error:

`alarm_actions` - (Optional) The ***list*** of actions to execute when this alarm transitions into an ALARM state from any other state. Each action is specified as an Amazon Resource Name (ARN).

I simply needed to specify a list type for my variable and enclose the statement in `[]`.

Comment: issue is fixed or , you are getting the updated error ? ```Inappropriate value for attribute "alarm_actions": set of string required.```

Comment: The issue is fixed. The value needed to be a list as noted, the updated error in my edit is what I was actually getting for the issue.